# How to link a property setter to a delegate?

Tags: c#

I would like to give a property setter to a delegate. How is this done?

```
class A {
  private int count;
  public int Count {
    get { return count; }
    set { count = value; }
  }
}
A a = new A();   
delegate void ChangeCountDelegate(int x);
ChangeCountDelegate dlg = ... ? // should call a.Count = x
```

Comment: Just so you know, if you're using .NET 3.5 or higher, you really don't need to define this `ChangeCountDelegate`. `Action<int>` is the same thing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
ChangeCountDelegate dlg = (int x) => a.Count = x;

// or
ChangeCountDelegate dlg = x => a.Count = x;

// or 
ChangeCountDelegate dlg = new ChangeCountDelegate(delegate(int x) { a.Count = x; } );

// or 
ChangeCountDelegate dlg = new ChangeCountDelegate(int x => a.Count = x);
```

Or am I thinking to easy? :)

I'm sure you get the point.

The 3rd one works in .NET 2.0, the others need at least 3.5 :)

Comment: This is very much verbose, not quite linq-style ;-)

Comment: I like verbose :) elegant coding.

Comment: I believe you could also go with the third option, without the explicit use of `new`, even in 2.0.

Comment: I like those answers with multiple ways to the target shown... very nice!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
ChangeCountDelegate dlg = v => a.Count = v;
```

Answer (score 1):

C# does not support Property-Delegates.

You can work with anonymous methods in the way Snake mentioned if you need to.